# ACRA 5.9 sends HTTP error report multiple times

Tags: android, acra

After upgrading our app to ACRA 5.9 I found that error reports are sent by HttpSender multiple times.

ACRA is initialized like this:

```
ACRA.init(this, new CoreConfigurationBuilder()
    .withBuildConfigClass(BuildConfig.class)
    .withReportFormat(StringFormat.KEY_VALUE_LIST)
    .withPluginConfigurations(
                    new ToastConfigurationBuilder()
                                    .withText(getString(R.string.crash_toast_text))
                                    .build()
                    )
    .withPluginConfigurations(
                    BuildConfig.DEBUG ?
                    new LimiterConfigurationBuilder()
                                    .withPeriod(1)
                                    .withPeriodUnit(TimeUnit.DAYS)
                                    .withOverallLimit(250)
                                    .withExceptionClassLimit(100)
                                    .withStacktraceLimit(50)
                                    .withFailedReportLimit(50)
                                    .withIgnoredCrashToast("App stopped working again")
                                    .build() :
                    new LimiterConfigurationBuilder()
                                    .withPeriod(7)
                                    .withPeriodUnit(TimeUnit.DAYS)
                                    .withOverallLimit(25)
                                    .withExceptionClassLimit(10)
                                    .withStacktraceLimit(5)
                                    .withFailedReportLimit(5)
                                    .withIgnoredCrashToast("App stopped working again")
                                    .build()
    )
    .withPluginConfigurations(
                    new HttpSenderConfigurationBuilder()
                                    .withConnectionTimeout(8000)
                                    .withDropReportsOnTimeout(true)
                                    .withUri(fs.getCrashReportUrl())
                                    .build()
    )
    .withReportContent(fields)
);
```

Custom HTTP sender is created like this:

```
@AutoService(ReportSenderFactory.class)

public class MyCrashSenderFactory implements ReportSenderFactory {

    private static final String TAG = MyCrashSenderFactory.class.getSimpleName();

    @NonNull
    public ReportSender create(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull CoreConfiguration config) {

        MySettings fs = new MySettings(context);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG,"ACRA create sender for "+fs.getCrashReportUrl());
        return new HttpSender(config, HttpSender.Method.POST, StringFormat.KEY_VALUE_LIST, fs.getCrashReportUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enabled(@NonNull CoreConfiguration coreConfig) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The logcat after a simple crash looks like this:

```
14:17:25.358  E  ACRA caught a ArithmeticException for com.myapp
                 java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
                    at com.myapp.MenuItemHandler.handleMenuClick(MenuItemHandler.java:128)
...
14:17:25.452  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
14:17:25.468  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
14:17:25.511  E  USNET: appName: com.myapp:acra
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (2569) for package com.myapp ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (2036) for package com.myapp ----------------------------
14:17:25.896  D  ACRA registered
14:17:25.983  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
14:17:26.006  I  Sending report /data/user/0/com.myapp/app_ACRA-approved/2023-02-11T14:17:25.380+07:00.stacktrace
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (2606) for package com.myapp ----------------------------
14:17:27.088  I  ACRA is enabled for com.myapp, initializing...
14:17:27.227  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
14:17:27.237  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
14:17:27.277  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
14:17:27.278  I  Sending report /data/user/0/com.myapp/app_ACRA-approved/2023-02-11T14:17:25.380+07:00.stacktrace
14:17:27.732  I  Request received by server
14:17:28.318  I  Request received by server
14:17:28.907  I  Request received by server
14:17:29.863  I  Request received by server
14:17:29.868  W  Could not delete file: /data/user/0/com.myapp/app_ACRA-approved/2023-02-11T14:17:25.380+07:00.stacktrace
```

The report is sent 4 times. If a custom HTTP sender is not used then 2 times. Is there a way to avoid multiple sends?

EDIT: If I disable the HttpSender by ACRA config I still get about 6 custom HttpSender created and 2 reports sent. Here is the logcat:

```
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (15606) for package com.myapp ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (15894) for package com.myapp ----------------------------
08:50:18.794 15894-15894 com.myapp  I  ACRA is enabled for com.myapp, initializing...
08:50:36.376 15894-15894 com.myapp  E  ACRA caught a ArithmeticException for com.myapp
                                                                     java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
                                                                        at com.myapp.MenuItemHandler.handleMenuClick(MenuItemHandler.java:128)
...
08:50:36.457 15894-15894 com.myapp  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
08:50:36.466 15894-15894 com.myapp  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
08:50:36.539 16093-16093 pid-16093E  USNET: appName: com.myapp:acra
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (16093) for package com.myapp ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (15894) for package com.myapp ----------------------------
08:50:36.599 16093-16093 com.myapp  D  handleBindApplication()++ app=com.myapp:acra
08:50:37.040 16093-16120 com.myapp  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
08:50:37.063 16093-16120 com.myapp  I  Sending report /data/user/0/com.myapp/app_ACRA-approved/2023-02-12T08:50:36.395+07:00.stacktrace
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (16128) for package com.myapp ----------------------------
08:50:38.208 16128-16128 com.myapp  I  ACRA is enabled for com.myapp, initializing...
08:50:38.334 16128-16158 com.myapp  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
08:50:38.341 16128-16158 com.myapp  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
08:50:38.381 16093-16160 com.myapp  D  ACRA create sender for https://api.myapp.com/api/error_report.php
08:50:38.382 16093-16160 com.myapp  I  Sending report /data/user/0/com.myapp/app_ACRA-approved/2023-02-12T08:50:36.395+07:00.stacktrace
08:50:38.824 16093-16120 com.myapp  I  Request received by server
08:50:39.916 16093-16160 com.myapp  I  Request received by server
08:50:39.925 16093-16160 com.myapp  W  Could not delete file: /data/user/0/com.myapp/app_ACRA-approved/2023-02-12T08:50:36.395+07:00.stacktrace
```

Comment: Unclear why you get double reports per sender, but regarding custom sender: If you extend a sender you should disable the base version via config.

Comment: @F43nd1r Thx, I disabled the HttpSender by adding `withEnabled(false)` to the `HttpSenderConfigurationBuilder()`. Still getting 5 or 6 of custom `HttpSender` created and two reports sent. I added the new logcat to my question. Can the issue result of the fact that the app is holding a Foreground Service and the app process (16128) is getting restarted immediately after crash?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm. The multiple sending issue doesn't occur if I disable the Foreground Service in our app and the ACRA process has enough time to complete the report sending before the main process restarts. Is there a way to use ACRA with the Foreground Service?

Comment: Report Senders will be created multiple times due to requiresForeground checks, this is expected. Sending twice is not.

Comment: In case you're using multiple processes make sure to read http://www.acra.ch/docs/Troubleshooting-Guide#applicationoncreate

Comment: In general this does sound like a bug to me. Lets continue the discussion here: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/1161